# Duplicating entities from EF Core into MongoDB on Creation or Edit

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an asp.net core project that has both sql server and mongodb. the task is to add or update any entity that is being added or updated to sql server(using ef core), to mongo.
I figured I can override OnSaveChangesAsync but I have no idea how to access the entities that are being changed there in order to call the mongo service's update and insert methods on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using interceptors:

The Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class StudentsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .AddInterceptors(new UpdateMongoInterceptor())
            .UseSqlite(@"DataSource=C:\Databases\Students.db");
    }
}
```

SaveChangesInterceptor:

```
public class UpdateMongoInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        UpdateMongoDb(eventData.Context);
        return result;
    }

    private static void UpdateMongoDb(DbContext context)
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                case EntityState.Added:
                    if (entry.Entity is Student student)
                    {
                        //Update MongoDB...
                        Console.WriteLine($"Push student entity to mongoDB  Id: {student.Id}, Name:{student.Name}, Age:{student.Age}");
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usege:

```
using (var context = new StudentsContext())
{
    var student = new Student {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Jon Snow", Age = 25};

    context.Add(student);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Interceptors documentations can be found here: [Example: SaveChanges interception for auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception)

** If you are using DB generated keys you should override `SavedChanges` and figure out of the entity was updated or added.